# onde ficam as rotas de login no laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, rotas, laravel-rotas

Cadastrei algumas rotas autenticadas(já tenho as páginas de autenticação criadas com o `make:auth`) e elas funcionam certinho, sempre que eu tento acessar essas rotas em uma aba anonima ele cai no endereço

```
http://localhost/siteBaldesbr/public/login
```

a minha duvida é: onde estão configuradas as rotas de autenticação que definem o destino de páginas como por exemplo, "/login", "register" entre outras?

Answer (score 2):

Dentro do seu arquivo routes/web.php possui um "Auth::routes();", é ai onde ficam as rotas, é o padrão do auth

Comment: entendi...mas como faço para editar as rotas?em qual arquivo se encontram os detalhes de  Auth::routes(); ?

Comment: Ai voce precisa reescrever as mesmas, criar rotas com os mesmos nomes e assim serão sobreescritas